# how can i get my div contents to stop extending past my other div

Tags: html, css, alignment

ok, I am new to this. I have only been doing it for a few months.

I am trying to make a web page for my school.

I ran into a problem, I have different div, containers to hold my site.

I have my `.BodyBackground` (holds my background picture)

inside that div I have the rest:

I have `.allContent` (which holds the rest of the web page0)

inside that div I have `.LeftGroup`, `.MiddleGroup`, and `.RightGroup`.
3 different div's to hold different styles of text/information.

at the bottom of that I have my `.footer` div.

Now! they are all in the right place.

But the `.LeftGroup`, and the `.RightGroup` are extending past the div that they are placed in.

the `.MiddleGroup` is indented at the location that it hits the `.LeftGroup` div.

I have spent hours trying different things to figure this out without success.
can someone please help me..

the site code shouldn't matter to much, I explained what was going on with the code its in the style sheet.

Here is the CSS (style) code... (this is my first time I hope it shows up right )

```
 .BodyBackground      {
               background-image: url ('../Pictures/Background.jpg');
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           padding-top: 1%;
           padding-bottom: 1%;
           padding-left: 17%;
           padding-right: 17%;
           position: fixed;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;
           right: 0;
           bottom: 0;
           -webkit-background-size: cover;
           -moz-background-size: cover;
           background-size: cover;
           background-position:center center;
           z-index: 0;
           overflow: auto;
           height: 100%;                                           }

  .AllContent      {
               background-image: url('../Pictures/BackgroundFour.png'); 
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           position: center;
           -webkit-background-size: cover;
           -moz-background-size: cover;
           background-size: cover;
           background-position:center center;
           box-sizing: border-box;
           width: auto;
           height: auto;
           padding: 20px;
           border-style: solid;
               border-color: orange;
           }

   .headerOne      {
        background-image: url('../Pictures/Background.jpg');
           box-sizing: border-box;
           width: 100%;
           padding: 10px;
           height: 200px;
           box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #333333;
           }

 .headerTwo        {                        
           font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
           box-sizing: border-box;
           width: 375px;
           height: 70px;
           padding: 0px;
           overflow: hidden;
           white-space: nowrap;     
           text-indent: 3%;
           font-weight: bold;
           font-size: 18px;
           color: white;
           margin-bottom: 1%;
           position: relative;
           top: 37%;
           }


 .navOne               {
           box-sizing: border-box;
           width: 100%;
           padding: 2px;
           height: 20px;
           box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333333;
           margin-top: 1%;
           margin-bottom: 3%;
           position: relative;
           top: 35%;
           font-size: 12px;
           font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
           font-weight: bold;
           text-indent: 6%;                 
           background-color: #3D75D5;
           overflow: hidden;
           white-space: nowrap;
           }

  a:hover          {
           color: Brown;
           }    

  nav a        {
           color: white;
           }    



  .LeftGroup       {
           box-sizing: border-box;
           background-color: white;
           width: 20%;
           padding: 10px;
           height: auto;
           margin-top: 1%;
           position: relative;
           float: left;
           }

  .RightGroup      }
                   box-sizing: border-box;
           background-color: white;
           width: 20%;
           padding: 10px;
           height: auto;
           margin-top: 1%;
           position: relative;
           float: right;
           }

  .MiddleGroup     {
           box-sizing: border-box;
           background-color: lightblue;
           margin-top: 1%;
           width: 60%;
           padding: 10px;
           height: auto;
           position: relative;
           left:20%;
               float: center;
               }                        

  .Footer          {
           box-sizing: border-box;
           background-color: gray;
           margin-top: 0;
           width: auto;
           bottom: 0;
           padding: 5px;
           position: relative;
           text-align: center;
           color: white;

                    }
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code, you never know when it's relevant

Comment: And please do not always post the whole source code. Post what seems relevant to your question. It otherwise is hard to find what exactly is relevant for the answering the post.

Answer (score 1):

- please check the line - `.RightGroup      }`. You have added the closing brace instead of opening brace `{`.
- remove the `position: relative; left:20%;` from `.MiddleGroup` and add a `float: left;` instead.  Also remove `float: center;`. there is no such value for `float`.
- finally add a `overflow: hidden;` to `.AllContent`
- `.BodyBackground` and `.AllContent` don't need the `position:` style. you can remove them. `position: center;` is wrong.

Comment: '.allContent{position:' should have 'relative | fixed | absolute | static ' value rather than 'center'.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap grid alignment.Download Bootstrap from [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/) and use `<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-md-4>` use this col-md class in your row.

Grid system has 12 columns in a web page where it can be divided as 4, 4, 4 and 8, 4 and so on. So better use bootstrap.

Comment: thanks for the advise everyone, I cant use bootstrap. This is for school I have to do it myself. but thanks, I will check it out later. I am trying the other ideas now....

Comment: ok, I added most of the  advice, and go  it to work great so far. thanks a lot for the help...